# Apache Tomcat: lib folder

Tags: api, tomcat, servlets

I'm developing a webapp using Apache Tomcat. I have been told to use a folder called "servlet-api.jar". In the following image, you can see how it is structured:
Link to image: http://i44.tinypic.com/29g605.png

I put it in the lib directory of Tomacat but the webapp is not working.
Am I missing something?

Comment: what do you mean by not working? stack trace please.

Comment: My servlets print to screen some lines but they don't appear on the Tomcat console

Comment: can you add those lines in the question.It is hard to help without stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat provides the Servlet API classes for you: you don't have to provide them yourself. In order to *compile* your code, you will likely need that JAR file on the `CLASSPATH`. Tomcat should ignore the `servlet-api*.jar` file to protect itself, so your problem is likely unrelated to installing that library.